# Update and fetch a record from Entity Framework in a single query

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, code-first

I am working on a hotel management system and I am trying to make a query which will check the booking timing, and if the timing is over, it will close the booking and return a room type.

Close the booking means it will turn it's status to `false` and it will return a room type now the problem is that this query:

```
var Records = db.BookingInformation
                .Where(t => t.EndDate <= serverDate)
                .Where(t => t.Booking == true)
                .Select(t => t.RoomType).ToList();
```

This is returning a room type, but it's not turning booking to `false`. Any help?

I know that I haven't tried to update booking but I don't know how to do it.

Comment: Records just returns a list of records. you want to update everything within the list? i dont think EF supports bulk update for entities. you have to create your own scenario like with foreach ( `I DO NOT RECOMMEND` ), anyhow what you want exactly?

Comment: Above query is fetching those records where booking is closed. I want to fetch them as well as turn their booking status to false. Either this can be done by one query or two. Help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you willing to use stored procedures? or entirely EF and linq to entities?

Comment: linq would be good

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this out, should do what you are asking for:

```
var records = db.BookingInformation
    .Where(t => t.EndDate <= serverDate)
    .Where(t => t.Booking == true).ToList()
      .Select(t => {t.Booking = false; return t.RoomType;});
```

Call SaveChanges after executing this, otherwise the changes will not be persisted to the DB.

Comment: I am getting an error "a lamda expression with a statement body cannot be converted to an expression tree"

Comment: I made a small change so the query is triggered before changing the data. Try now....